# Plotting a csv file from wireshark

Tags: gnuplot, wireshark

I saved a wireshark sniffer capture file as csv.  All the elements are saved within the double quotation.  I am trying to plot the graph over the same. csv file and the gnuplot code is given.  All the values came up to a single xtic label.  Can someone help me giving a workaround to plot using the doublequotes in the data file.

```html
data.csv

"No.",Time",Source,Destination,Protocol
"2",0.000252",192.168.1.183,224.0.0.251,MDNS
"3",0.000553",192.168.1.183,224.0.0.251,MDNS
"4",0.00102",192.168.1.183,224.0.0.251,MDNS
"6",0.10285",192.168.1.183,224.0.0.251,MDNS
"9",0.307653",192.168.1.183,224.0.0.251,MDNS
"12",0.512459",192.168.1.183,224.0.0.251,MDNS
"15",0.717208",192.168.1.183,224.0.0.251,MDNS
"1876",57.027387",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1878",57.051959",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1879",57.076533",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1880",57.101105",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1881",57.125798",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1883",57.150375",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1884",57.174908",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1885",57.199418",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1886",57.223989",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1888",57.248572",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1889",57.273146",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1890",57.297719",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1891",57.322295",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1893",57.347335",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1894",57.371452",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1895",57.396097",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1896",57.420663",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1898",57.445152",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1899",57.469746",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1900",57.494326",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1901",57.518902",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
"1902",57.543474",,Cisgram_89:0c:e9 (00:77:4c:89:0c:e9) (RA),802.11
```

```html
gnuplot> reset
gnuplot> set datafile separator ","
gnuplot> set xdata time
gnuplot> set timefmt '"%s.%.6s"'
gnuplot> set xtic rotate 90
gnuplot>
gnuplot> plot 'data.csv' u 2:1:xtic(2) w linespoint
Warning: empty x range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]
gnuplot>
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldnt the timefmt just be `%s` or `%S`?

Answer (score 0):

If your time is in seconds and you want to plot the x-axis in seconds then there is no need to use `set xdata time`. Unless you want the x-axis units displayed in minutes or hours. Independent of that, using `xtic(2)` is also not needed in both cases. gnuplot is interpreting column 2 as floating point number ignoring the `"`.

If I correctly assume what you want to plot, your plot command would simply be:

```
plot $Data  u 2:1 with linespoints
```