# Gnuplot: substring fetching from csv file

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to extract a string from a csv capture.  I am trying to plot labels on the graph.

```html
data.csv

"No.","Time","Source","Destination","Protocol","Info"
"2","0.000252","192.168.1.183","224.0.0.251","802.11","Standard query 0x0000 ANY 43684enet3-15988.local, ""QM"" question HINFO X86_64 LINUX"
"3","0.000553","192.168.1.183","224.0.0.251","802.11","Standard query response 0x0000 AAAA, cache flush fe80::e2d5:5eff:fe51:b860 A, cache flush 192.168.1.183"
```

I try to plot a substring of field, using the script:

```html
set colors classic
set terminal svg size 360,460
set output 'reading.svg'

set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s.%.6s"
set xtic rotate 90

plot 'data.csv' u 1:2:(substr($4,1,3)):xtic(2) with labels
```

I tried to extract substring from the columns.  But it is giving the following error:

```html
C:\Users\ys928695\Box\TWT>gnuplot script.gpc
"script.gpc" line 19: internal error: substring range operator applied to non-STRING type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gnuplot is interpreting `$4` as floating point number. If you want to have it interpreted as string you need to use `strcol()` or `stringcolumn()`, see `help stringcolumn`.

So the following should work:

```
plot 'data.csv' u 1:2:(substr(strcol(4),1,3)) with labels
```

By the way, the same in [your other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61972694/7295599), I wouldn't use `xtic(2)` if you want to use seconds as the x-axis.